# Mapbox with collapsible sidebar

Tags: html, jquery, mapbox

I have followed earlier post on stack and created mapbox page with a sidebar. The example I followed is on this url: [Adding collapsible sidebar to mapbox map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642804/adding-collapsible-sidebar-to-mapbox-map)

I need to move the sidebar to the right of the page. I have made CSS modifications and replaced Javascript with Jquery.

The code works however the map wont shift to the left. The example I followed appears to show the map move when sidebar expands.

Can someone please advise what needs to be done?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Mapbox: Collapsible sidebar</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />


<style>
 body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html, body, #map{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:10px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  position:relative;
  transition: margin-right .8s;
  height:100%;

}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>



</head>




<body>



<!--For Interactive Sidebar Body-->

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>


<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
 <div id='map'></div>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  var attr = $("#mySidebar").attr('custom');
  if (typeof attr == 'undefined' || attr == "false") {
    $("#mySidebar").width(250);
    $("#main").css("margin-right", "250px");
    $("#mySidebar").attr("custom", "true");
}else {
  $("#mySidebar").width(0);
  $("#main").css("margin-right", "0");
  $("#mySidebar").attr("custom", "false");
}
}

</script>

<!--End Interactive Sidebar Body-->

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFubnljaG9oYW4iLCJhIjoiY2xmb2NkZmluMHU4eTN3cXowMXQ3a2pjNyJ9.xylD3VfG_ImmIy4cAZIvvg';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [0, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 2 // starting zoom
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did u saw the answer on your first post ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642804/adding-collapsible-sidebar-to-mapbox-map